# How to set ACL on HDFS command like -put, -get

Tags: hdfs, acl

In a cluster we want to restrict the usage of HDFS commands like `hdfs dfs -put -get` so that the user cannot arbitrarily upload and download data between Hadoop and local OS

Is it possible? will there be any impact to other normal functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hdfs-site.xml you need to enable `dfs.namenode.acls.enabled` to `true`.

Then to use ACLs, use the commands `hdfs dfs -setfacl` and `hdfs dfs -getacl`

#### References

- [Filesystem Shell: setfacl](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#setfacl)
- [Filesystem Shell: getfacl](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getfacl)
- [HDFS Permissions Guide: ACLs (Access Control Lists)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_Access_Control_Lists)
- Performance considerations: [why are HDFS ACL max_entries set to 32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214397/why-are-hdfs-acl-max-entries-set-to-32)